# There are 4 fields based on its values combination we have to filter the data in Mulesoft

Tags: dataweave, mulesoft, mule4, mule-esb

There are 4 fields based on its values combination we have to filter the data in Mulesoft.
Example:

#### Input payload 1:

```
{
 "Msg": {
  "Code": "abc",
  "Chcode": "123",
  "Dcode": "55",
  "Type": "pqr"
 }
}
```

#### Input payload 2:

```
{
 "Msg": {
   "Code": "klm",
   "Chcode": "789",
   "Dcode": "32",
   "Type": "xyz"
 }
}
```

#### Input payload 3:

```
{
 "Msg": {
  "Code": "klm",
  "Chcode": "456",
  "Dcode": "22",
  "Type": "shi"
 }
}
```

Filter condition: Input payload should match with Code, Chcode, Dcode and Type.
Example: Input payload should contain Code=abc, Chcode=123, Dcode=55, Type=pqr

| Code | Chcode | Dcode | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 55 | pqr |
| ghl | 456 | 22 | shi |
| ghi | 276 | 3u | foh |

The input payload 1 matches the first row in filter condition like code,Chcode,Dcode and Type are same. So that record should be filtered for processing. Input payload 3 matches with Chcode,Dcode and Type but not with Code so this record is to be ignored.

Like these above combinations, there are 45 combinations, how to filter this type of records in Mulesoft.

Comment: What is the criteria? if any of the conditions match the record should be filtered? If all the fields match? Please provide some examples. Note that the quotes are not valid in your input.

Comment: What @aled said--please express your questions in a clear and succinct manner, preferably using SO's text formatting rules.

Comment: Note that your JSON input is also invalid. I guess that you want Msg to be an array.

Comment: I have updated the question with SO's text formatting rules and also corrected the json. could you please help.

Comment: How are these values stored ? The table that is which contains these combinations ? Can these be an array each for code , chcode , dcode and type ?

Comment: @Salim Khan These filter conditions are not stored anywhere, it is the combination which we have to use to filter the data.

Comment: You would still need to refer those from some sort of storage. Ale has posted the answer with that approach (Storing the filter conditions in an array of objects ) and that should be the ideal way to do that.

Comment: Mine is just an example of the conditions logic so I fixed the array in a script variable. It could be a Mule variable coming from a database or a configuration file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script is an example of how to implement the condition checking:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::core::Objects
var conditionsTable=[
    {Code: "abc", Chcode: "123", Dcode:"55", Type: "pqr"},
    {Code: "ghl", Chcode: "456", Dcode:"22", Type: "shi"},
    {Code: "ghl", Chcode: "276", Dcode:"3u", Type: "foh"}
]
fun matchRecord(record, cond)=record everyEntry (value, key) -> cond[key] == value
fun matchConditions(record, conditions)=conditions some ((item) -> matchRecord(record, item))
---
matchConditions(payload.Msg, conditionsTable)
```

Comment: Thank you aled, it's working perfectly as per the requirement. If there are additional fields in input payload this logic will not work.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the question but you can modify the function matchRecord() easily to add that requirement by only considering the fields that are in the conditions record: `fun matchRecord(record, cond)=record everyEntry (value, key) -> if(cond[key]?) (cond[key] == value) else true`